# The values returned from Firebase are equal to null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get username from the database firebase but the data returned is equal to null.

**This is database structure:**
[image: Database Structure]

> **This is code snippet:**

```
 if (getIntent() != null)
            //get id for the user to send the message to
            chatUser = getIntent().getExtras().getString("user_id");
        Log.v(TAG, "Intent Extra: " + chatUser);

        DatabaseReference userChild = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("users")
                .child(chatUser);

        userChild.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String username = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("fullName").getValue());
                Log.v(TAG, "username: " + username);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Check firebase rules once. And also what is the result of Log.v(TAG, "Intent Extra: " + chatUser);

Comment: Nothing in your code returns anything. Do you mean that the `Log.v(TAG, "username: " + username);` writes `null`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes, Log writes null.

Comment: @Raj the result is 2jK5NQRQ3vSecL261a3rzoXM6853

Comment: Put this inside onDataChange Log.i("DataSnapshot", dataSnapshot.toString()); and tell the result ?

Comment: @Raj the result is **DataSnapshot { key = 2jK5NQRQ3vSecL261a3rzoXM6853 , value = null }**

Comment: Is your code available on github. I need to see full code

Comment: @Raj I'll upload it on Github and write the link.

Comment: Can you change `userChild.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {` to `userChild.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {`and see if it then prints twice?

Comment: Have you tried mapping the snapshot values to a model? You can take a look at [firebase android quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/database/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/database/NewPostActivity.java#L83)

Comment: @HassanSalah Have you tried what Frank van Puffelen suggested?

Answer (score -1):

I have created a Java model. try the code below:-

```
public User(){
    public String country;
    public String email;
    public String fullName;
    public String username;
}


userChild.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class));
        String username = user.username;
        Log.v(TAG, "username: " + username);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```